# positioning images in a CSS-grid coming from Python

Tags: python, html, css, grid

I have images read out of a database by Python in the form

```
for i in images:
    print >> htmlpage, "<img src='../folder/%s'>" % i
```

giving me an output on a static html-page like

```
<img src='../folder/image01.jpg'>
<img src='../folder/image02.jpg'>
<img src='../folder/image03.jpg'>
<img src='../folder/image04.jpg'>
```

I would like the images to be displayed in a grid of five columns. I have tried to do position them in a `<table>` during output but could not get a working syntax with all `<tr>` and `<td>`s. I was wondering if I could just put them in a `<div>` and let my .css Stylesheet handling the grid-layout?

I don't know what could be the most elegant solution, generating a well-formatted but simple html-page generated by Python-code? I hope someone has a clue, hint, trick.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: A table sounds like it would work well for this (tabular data).  Why didn't that approach work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all images have the same width you could wrap all the images in a container, give the container a width equal to the images width*5 and float the images. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YDUsz/

I don't know python, so this might be stupid, but hopefully you'll get what I mean:

```
<div clas="image-wrapper">
for i in images:
    print >> htmlpage, "<img src='../folder/%s'>" % i
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-wrapper {
    width: (Image width * 5);
}
.image-wrapper img {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This would probably be the best solution. If the image-wrapper was made smaller then the number of columns would adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I also think, that tables are the most reasonable approach.

Did you try something like this:

```
print "<table>"
for i in range(len(image)):
    if i % 5 == 0:
            print "<tr><td>"
    print >> htmlpage, "<img src='../folder/%s'>" % image[i]
    if i % 5 == 4:
            print "</td></tr>"
if len(image) % 5 != 0:
    print "</td></tr>"
print "</table>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a counter in order to detect where the ending /TR and new TR should go.

Set a variable before the FOR loop which sets a=1

In your FOR loop, at the bottom of it put a++ which will increase a by 1 each loop.

Right before a++ have an IF to check and see if a=5 in which case you should print /TR TR.